# Cannot type in Google colab cells

Tags: google-colaboratory

I just started using Google colaboratory. But I cannot type in the code or text cells. I can copy-paste and delete though. Im accessing via Chrome (latest version for Windows 10).
What have I got wrong?

Comment: Does this issue reproduce in an incognito window with all extensions disabled? Does this behavior persist in all notebooks, or only one? (It's possible you have loaded a read-only notebook and need to make a copy or load in playground mode in order to edit.)

Comment: Restarting chrome or restarting computer worked when I had similar issue with windows10. Try it

Comment: upgraded chrome and restarted the machine. Tried with a new notebook of my own as well. FInally, installed Firefox, and all works fine. Seems like an issue with chrome.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be rather simple but for me it solved the problem when I was using Chrome in Windows 10.

1. Terminate the session
2. Reload the page

Answer (score 1):

[Bug report](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/966)

The same thing happened with me. I just disabled google input tools extension and it started working for me.

Comment: how do you disable input tools extension?

Comment: I just deleted google input tools extension.

Answer (score 1):

In Colab , Tools-->Keyboard Shortcuts...>Change the mode of Editor key bindings as "Deafault"